# VBA Automation error with CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")

Tags: excel, vba

I can successfully run a VBA script in a .xlsm file on my own computer but after moving the xlsm file to a different computer, that computer throws an automation error? So how do I fix it so the script runs on the other computer?

The xlsm contains a class module that implements the script described here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196076/bringing-the-system-text-stringbuilder-up-to-lightning-speed-in-the-vba
I think this maybe a framework.NET issue so I have installed the System.Text onto the other computer (via installation of VS) and successfully tested it through a really simple C# command console.
The VBA code that fails is the following (in the Class_Initialize sub-routine):

```
Set m.Builder = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
```

When I attempt to run the VBA I get a message box with the following content:

> Run-time error '-2146232576 (80131700)' Automation error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I followed the successful answer given in this post:
[automation error -2146232576 (80131700) on creating an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40625618/automation-error-2146232576-80131700-on-creating-an-array?rq=1)

It worked for me too.

I needed to install .NET Framework 3.5 which I did by following the advice given here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10