# What options do I have to CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file we share among a lot of people at work. The past five years the code has worked fine, but now a new guy is introduced to the file and he get the (links to other threads about the error) [automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40625618/automation-error-2146232576-80131700-on-creating-an-array) [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58776731/use-system-collections-arraylist-in-vba-what-net-framework-version-is-needed) on this part below:

```
        Dim TillfLevdagar(1 To 14) As String
        .... 
        ' code that sets some of the array items above
        .....


        Dim arr2 As Object

        Set arr2 = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") ' here it errors
        
        For Each itm In TillfLevdagar
            If itm <> "" Then arr2.Add CInt(itm)
        Next
        arr2.Sort

        For Each itm In arr2
            msg = msg & itm & ","
        Next
```

Since this is a work computer we are very limited in allowing any software to be installed. That includes Microsoft software.
Becuase of this I ask what alternatives do I have to the code above?

Comment: You could use a `Dictionary` and implement the sort by yourself, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808104/sorting-a-dictionary-by-key-in-vba

Comment: Since `TillfLevdagar` exists and you need the `arrayList` only for sorting, create a simple function to directly sort the existing array. Then, iterate between the `TillfLevdagar` (sorted) array elements.

Comment: @Andreas, does your IT dept really prevent you installing  an older MS .Net framework on a new PC, even though other PCs already have it?

Comment: @chrisneilsen I believe they do. If you can say no, then a no it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next sorting way and use only the initial (`TillfLevdagar`) array:

```
Sub BubbleSort(arr)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, temp
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(i) > arr(j) Then
                temp = arr(i): arr(i) = arr(j)
                arr(j) = temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

You can test it using the next testing procedure:

```
Sub testBubbleSort()
   Dim arr, arrStr(1 To 14) As String, i As Long
   arr = Split("test,boolean,core,leaf,dream,crises,bet,arrow", ",")
   For i = 1 To 14
        arrStr(i) = Chr(Int((25 + 1) * Rnd + 1) + 64) & "test"
   Next i
   BubbleSort arr
   Debug.Print Join(arr, "|")
   BubbleSort arrStr
   Debug.Print Join(arrStr, "|")
End Sub
```

I have this sorting sub in my testing collection Subs, from some years. I do not remember where from I found it and what I adapted, if I did that. It is a simple sorting procedure. Anyhow, I used it many times with good results.